# Sending a POST request locally in C++ on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, http, go, localhost

I have a c++ client and and golang server on the same pc (on windows 10), and I want the client to send POST requests to the server. The request I want to send is the /test one. Both projects compile and run well, but the requests are not handled by the client, even if the server is showing

```
"HTTP-GA-SERVER: POST Successfully sent"
```

Here is the C++ code :

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include "ga-http-post.h"

int sendPostToMushroom(HttpRequestType req, void* metrics)
{
    WSADATA wsaData;
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData) != 0) {
        std::cout << "WSAStartup failed." << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    SOCKET Socket=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP);

    SOCKADDR_IN SockAddr;
    SockAddr.sin_port=htons(8080);
    SockAddr.sin_family=AF_INET;
    SockAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_LOOPBACK);

    std::cout << "HTTP-GA: Connecting..." << std::endl;

    if (Socket < 0) {
        std::cout << "HTTP-GA: Error creating socket: " << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    if(connect(Socket,(SOCKADDR*)(&SockAddr),sizeof(SockAddr)) != 0){
        std::cout << "HTTP-GA: Error connecting: " << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    std::cout << "HTTP-GA: Connected to " << inet_ntoa(SockAddr.sin_addr) << std::endl;

    char buffer[2048];
    strcpy(buffer,"POST /test HTTP/1.1\n");

    if (send(Socket,buffer, strlen(buffer),0) != strlen(buffer))
    {
        std::cout << "HTTP-GA: Error sending:" << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    closesocket(Socket);
    WSACleanup();
    std::cout << "HTTP-GA: POST Successfully sent" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And the golang code :

```
func (a *Agent) runGaHTTPHandler() {
    fmt.Println("HTTP : Init HTTP Server")

    http.HandleFunc("/ready", a.handleServerReady)
    http.HandleFunc("/unavailable", a.handleServerUnavailable)
    http.HandleFunc("/connected", a.handleClientConnected)
    http.HandleFunc("/disconnected", a.handleServerUnavailable)
    http.HandleFunc("/MetricsCollected", a.handleMetrics)
    http.HandleFunc("/test", a.handleTest)

    fmt.Println("HTTP : Listen and serve")
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}

func (a *Agent) handleTest(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Print("HTTP : Test successful\n")
}
```

EDIT : C++ code changed, still not working

Comment: "I want the server to send POST requests to the client." - is it a typo? Don't you want the C++ client to send requests to he Go server? (sorry if I misunderstand).  Also you say 'the server is showing "HTTP-GA-SERVER: POST Successfully sent"' - but this message is in the c++ **client** code...

Comment: @dmitris It was a typo, and my log messages are misleading. Sorry for that, i have edited the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit** 
In the client code, try to change:
`strcpy(buffer,"POST /test HTTP/1.1\n");`
to
`strcpy(buffer,"POST /test HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: localhost\r\n\r\n");`

HTTP/1.1 requires the presence of the `Host` HTTP header; after the headers, there should be an extra newline (`\r\n`).  Of course, change `localhost` to the actual hostname if needed.

[Previous answer regarding the Go http server code]
In the `handleTest` function, you need to write to the http.ResponseWriter `w` or use its `WriteHeader` and `Write` functions. Currently `fmt.Print` in your code most likely prints the string in the terminal where you started the Go server but does not send it to the client.  Try the following (simplified) version of your Go program:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/test", handleTest)

    fmt.Println("HTTP : Listen and serve")
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}

func handleTest(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Write([]byte("HTTP : Test successful\n"))
}
```

When you started the Go server, the client should get a response like this one done with curl (you can also access it through a browser for testing) :

```
$ curl http://localhost:8080/test
HTTP : Test successful
```

You can see the description of the `ResponseHeader`'s `Write` and `WriteHeader` functiosn in the documentation for the net/http package: https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ResponseWriter

Comment: Hi !

Thanks for the fast answer. Actually I want to print the message in the console, not to send it to the client. The client is sending stuff and does not wait for any answers :) I have try the curl command, and it is correctly outputing the message I want, so the problem comes frm the c++ code

Comment: I see - edited the answer to recommend sending a valid `Host` HTTP header in the request from the c++ client